# How to prevent BeautifulSoup from converting entities?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a BeautifulSoup Tag named *keyword*, and when I use `keyword.decode(formatter=None)`
to get the html text, I got this

```
<pre><span id="VAL(<>)"><span class="keyword">val</span> (<>)</span> : <code class="type">'a -> 'a -> bool</code></pre>
```

But the original html text is

```
<pre><span id="VAL(<>)"><span class="keyword">val</span> (&lt;&gt;)</span> : <code class="type">'a -> 'a -> bool</code></pre><div class="info ">
```

You can see the `&lt;&gt;` is converted to `<>`. I just want the text to be exactly the same as it is in the original html file. So how can I prevent this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's missing something in the original

```
<pre><span id="VAL(<>)"><span class="keyword">val</span> <span>(&lt;&gt;)</span> : <code class="type">'a -> 'a -> bool</code></pre><div class="info ">

<span>(&lt;&gt;)</span>
```

Or it has an extra

```
 </span>
```

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't get your point. You mean the tag itself is wrong-formatted?

Comment: Not sure that it is even related to your problem after running it though but yes.  In the example above you have a closing tag without an open tag </span>.  Thought that could be related but I got the same thing as alKid.  Clearing formatter = None.

Comment: Maybe you should take a closer look at my code. There're exactly two opening `<span>` tags and two closing `</span>` tags in it. And BTW, as I commented on alKid's answer, removing `formatter=None` would result in `<>` being converted to `&lt;&gt;`, which also changes the original html.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `formatter=None`, just let it be. BeautifulSoup won't convert it.

```
>>> soup.prettify(formatter=None)
u'<pre>\n <span id="VAL(<>)">\n  <span class="keyword">\n   val\n  </span>\n  (<>)\n </span>\n :\n <code class="type">\n  \'a -> \'a -> bool\n </code>\n</pre>\n<div class="info ">\n</div>'
>>> soup
<pre><span id="VAL(&lt;&gt;)"><span class="keyword">val</span> (&lt;&gt;)</span> : <code class="type">'a -&gt; 'a -&gt; bool</code></pre><div class="info ">
</div>
>>> soup.prettify()
u'<pre>\n <span id="VAL(&lt;&gt;)">\n  <span class="keyword">\n   val\n  </span>\n  (&lt;&gt;)\n </span>\n :\n <code class="type">\n  \'a -&gt; \'a -&gt; bool\n </code>\n</pre>\n<div class="info ">\n</div>'
```

Comment: What exactly did you tried? Unless i'm mistaken, you don't have to convert anything.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. When I use `prettify()`, it converts `<>` to `&lt;&gt;`. And that's why I try to use `decode(formatter=None) instead, which didn't work either.

Comment: The original html code sometimes uses `&lt;&gt;` for displaying `<>`, and sometimes uses `<>` directly. Whatever, I just want the unchanged html text.