# &lt and &gt tags generated after applying the Beautifulsoup API replace_with?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, character-encoding

I followed the documentation of the [replace_with](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) Beautifulsoup API, but found that some symbols were changed.

```
markup = '<img src="https://abc/d.png"/> <br/>' 
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'html.parser') 
a_tag = soup.img 
svg_text = '<svg xmlns: </svg>' 
# new_tag.string = "example.net" 
# a_text = str(svg_text.encode('ascii').decode()) 
# b_text = svg_text.encode('unicode_escape') 
soup.find('img').replace_with(svg_text)
soup
```

What I expected is:

> `<svg xmlns: </svg> <br/>`

but what I got is:

> `&lt;svg xmlns: &lt;/svg&gt; <br/>`

I tried `svg_text.encode('unicode_escape')` and `str(svg_text.encode('ascii').decode())` as noted in the comment of the above snippet.

I get around the problem using this line:

```
soup.prettify(formatter=None)
```

But it introduced the unwanted `\n`:

> `<svg xmlns: </svg>\n<br/>\n`

Any suggestions? Could anyone please tell me why? Thanks in advance.

References:

1. [How can I insert a new tag into a BeautifulSoup object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21356014/3552975)
2. [How to prevent BeautifulSoup from converting entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20013788/3552975)

Comment: `import html; html.unescape('&lt;svg xmlns: &lt;/svg&gt; <br/>')`?

Comment: If you want to ditch the newlines that come with `prettify()` then instead of this `soup.prettify(formatter=None)` you can use `soup.decode(False, formatter=None)`. (Output will be - `'<svg xmlns: </svg> <br/>'`)

Comment: @JosefZ Could you please tell me why?